Web scrapping profootballreference in JupyterLite
Hello I am trying to figure out how web scrape www.profootballreference.com using JupyterLite (browser version). I already know how to do it using pycharm and now want to learn how to web scrape using JupyterLite. I know there are some restrictions to using the browser version which doesn't let me requests the html as it always leads to ConnectionError (ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', HTTPException("Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2022/'.")). I know so far that it depends on the requests headers that i need to specify, but do not know which other ones I need. I have already included the 'user-agent' header but would like to know which other ones i need to successfully get a request. here is what i have so far and the url i am trying to requests from.
import pandas as pd
import requests
team_stats_url = f'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2022/'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,  
like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
response = requests.get(url=team_stats_url, headers=headers).json()


this is not a json response. use text instead of json()

@wayne your links are not related, the first one is explicitly closed because not related to jupyterlite.

@Wayne that's not even the same error so i don't understand why you'd think those are good resources for the problem here. both issues are (probably) related to the javascript interpreter of jupyter. it's obvious for the second link that is about fetch. the first is more subtle but it's probably triggered by the oauth chain (which a regular requests.get can't handle). and i don't think that there's any javascript involved in op's question. unless i missed something (which is probable too)

@Wayne the github issues are not showing a requests limitation. the first one is not about the same error (and i suspect the oauth request is the problem, we don't know, the issue is closed because offtopic) and the second is not even about it. you just took the first hit searching 'jupyterlite requests' and are belittling the op for not doing enough research, which is to me a rather poor attitude. if you know there are limitations then you should be able to prove it (and your profile says proudly you can), but your links are failing to do so

For those looking to try the basics with OP's code: requests.get() apparently works fine in JupyterLite if you use a more straighforward static site. Change the team_stats_url line to team_stats_url = f'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments' and add the line response to the bottom of the cell and it will show the content at the URL. (That link comes from here. That code in the left side of the pane there also works in JupyterLite if you add fetch_data() at bottom of cell.)

Thanks for folen gatis pressing me on this. There was also this way to patch requests from last year, so I didn't expect requests to work out of the box in JupyterLite, but apparently it can now!

Raul, is there a particular part of the page you are trying to scrape to pandas? It may make a difference. Maybe not. For example, I based this code here on this example. Interestingly, the former works in JupyterLite, while substituting in the URL (or using code) from the latter fails in JupyterLite with the same error about Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'. All work in a full ipykernel.
